# Removing duplicate values in R based on comparing two columns

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I have a data like:

COL_1: First_Name

COL_2: Last_Name

```
COL_1      COL_2
Michel   Jackson
Meg      Ryan
Megan    Fox
Gerard   Butler
Simon    Baker
Ryan     Meg
Fox      Megan
Baker    Simon
Jackson  Amy
Simon    Baker
Baker    Simon
Simon    Richard
Baker    Richard
Meg      Ryan
Ryan     Meg
Meg      Meg
```

I want the output which clears the duplicate names comparing both the columns
for example **Meg Ryan** is same as **Ryan Meg**. Hence I need only one record either of **Meg Ryan** or **Ryan Meg** in the output.

The expected output is

```
COL_1      COL_2
Michel   Jackson
Meg      Ryan
Megan    Fox
Gerard   Butler
Simon    Baker
Jackson  Amy
Simon    Richard
Baker    Richard
Meg      Meg
```

P.S: I have few million records.

Comment: Make sure col1 < col2. Do UNION or SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: efficient and quick solution @jarlh. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df,1,sort))),]
      Col1    Col2
1   Michel Jackson
2      Meg    Ryan
3    Megan     Fox
4   Gerard  Butler
5    Simon   Baker
9  Jackson     Amy
12   Simon Richard
13   Baker Richard
16     Meg     Meg
```

Comment: Thanks Onyambu for the solution it works fine, Can we do this using dplyr ?

Comment: sure. just use `rowise`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

Method 1: you can remove duplicate rows from a data frame based on a column values, 
as follow:

## Remove duplicates based on my_data(data frame) COL_1 columns

```
my_data[!duplicated(my_data$COL_1), ]
```

Method 2: It’s also possible to apply unique() on a data frame, for removing duplicated rows as follow:

```
unique(my_data)
```

Method 3:

Step 1:- The "dplyr" package can be loaded and installed as follow:

## Install

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

## Load

```
library("dplyr")
```

Step 2:- Remove duplicate rows based on all columns using the 'dplyr' package:

```
distinct(my_data)
```

## Remove duplicated rows based on COL_1 and COL_2

```
distinct(my_data, COL_1 , COL_2)
```

Note :- distinct() is best-suited for interactive use. The function distinct_() should be used for calling from a function. In this case the input must be “quoted”.

```
distinct(my_data, "COL_1" , "COL_2")
```